# Show that exists a $x\in I$ such that $f(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $I=[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f:I\to I$ is a continous
>   function. Show that exists a $x\in I$ such that $f(x)=x$.

If $f$ is a continuous function in $I$ then $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ for any $c\in I$.

How can I ensure that this occurs for any function?

Comment: I am confused. Your question is "How can I ensure that **this** occurs for any function?" What does "this" refer to? If "this" refers to the property that $f$ must have a fixed point, then the conclusion will fail if you do not assume continuity or monotonicity (increasing).

Comment: Apply the intermediate value theorem to the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$. The fact that $f : I \to I$ means that $g(0) \ge 0$ and $g(1) \le 0$. If $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) < 0$, there must be a point $x \in I$ with $g(x) = 0$. Otherwise $g$ vanishes at an endpoint.

Comment: The definition you gave for continuity is actually the definition for uniform continuity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$, observe that $g(0) = f(0) - 0 \geq 0, g(1) = f(1) - 1 \leq 0$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Define the continuous function 
$$
g: [0,1] \to \mathbf{R}:x\mapsto f(x)-x.
$$

Then $g(0)=f(0)\ge 0$ and $g(1)=f(1)-1\le 0$. Hence there exists $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)=0$..

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to look at $g(x) =x-f(x)$ and show that $g(x) =0$ for some $x \in [0,1]$ .If $g(0) =0$ or $g(1)=0$ we are done ;otherwise $g(0)<0$ and $g(1)>0$ since $f(x)$ is in $[0,1]$. So use the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions to find the desired $x$.